# Select multiple fields but different rows in one query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select database data based on membership levels. If a member is level 1 he/she will be shown level 1 data, and if he/she is level 2 then they will see both level 1 and level 2 data.

Here is a table example:

```
member| membership_level 
------|----------------
john  |  1
------|-----------------
andy  |  2
```

Then I have PHP code that presents data based on membership_level, like so:

```
<?php if($userMember_level == 1) {  ?>
Show data for membership level 1
<?php }elseif($userMember_level == 2) {  ?>
Show data for membership level 1 And membership level 2
```

And here is my Mysqli statement:

```
//connect to database
require_once("../../db_query/connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT id,title,postdate FROM getting_started WHERE membership_level = ? AND active = ? AND membership_level = ? ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iii',$b=1,$a=1,$c=2);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result(); 
$numrow = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrow >0){

$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $postdate);

while($stmt->fetch()){ }

?>

<div class="resultWrap"> ...
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm not getting any results either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `but I'm not getting any results either` There're no `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump` in your code. Why are you sure that you don't get results?

Comment: membership level can never be one thing and also another thing !?!

Comment: I'm not so much concerned with echo, or print_r, or any error checking, I am doing all of that, it's just not being shown. My focus is on Selecting multiple rows from database, and getting results based on if members are at level 1 or level 2.

Comment: Your query will not work -> `WHERE membership_level = ? AND active = ? AND membership_level = ?`. It will never return a value where `membership_level = 1` **AND** `membership_level = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL you are looking for is:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT id,title,postdate
    FROM getting_started
    WHERE membership_level IN (?,?)
    AND active = ?
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
$stmt->bind_param('iii',1,2,1);
```

Comment: You sir, are a complete genius. I will be accepting your answer. Just thought I would add that comment, for saving me hours and hours of trouble. Thanks.